# Creating a class that represents 2D-points

Tags: python, class, 2d, points

Implement a class that represents 2D-points (i.e., a point that has an x- and a y- position) Implement the following methods:
distanceFromOrigin(): calculates and returns the distance to Point2D(0,0).

```
#this code
#p = Point2D(3,4)
#print(p.distanceFromOrigin())
#shall produce the following output
#5.0

import math

class Point2D:  
  def disctanceFromOrigin():
    dist = math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)
    return dist

p = Point2D(3,4)
print(p.distanceFromOrigin())
```

Can somebody tell me why this doesn't work?
It gives me back a TypeError: object() takes no parameters

Comment: you need to implement `__init__()` method for your class so that it can take arguments at instantiation. You should really look at basic tutorial on creating and working with class, because just this will not solve all your problems.

Comment: what is the use of `dist` just use `return math.sqrt((self.x2 - self.x1)**2 + (self.y2 - self.y1)**2)` Let `self` be a hint on what to do next

Comment: distance from origin is distance from `(0,0)` ie your `(x1, y1)` will be (0,0),   distance will be `dist = math.sqrt(x2**2+ y2**2)`, and you give (x2,y2) as arguments in your function, `p = Point2D()   print(p.disctanceFromOrigin(3,4))` and function shoul be `disctanceFromOrigin(self,x2,y2)` . if you want  to do `p = Point2D(3,4)` you will need `__init__()`

Comment: @Shijith aaah okey got it

Comment: Maybe you can refer source code of class turtle.Vec2D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import math

class Point2D:  
  def __init__(self, x, y):
      self.x = x
      self.y = y

  def disctanceFromOrigin(self):
    origin = Point2D(0, 0)
    dist = self.distanceFromPoint(self, origin)
    return dist
  
  def distanceFromPoint(self, point):
    return  math.sqrt((self.x - point.x)**2 + (self.y - point.y)**2


p = Point2D(3,4)
print(p.distanceFromOrigin())
```

Comment: @Shijith already showed me the right direction, but thanks anyway @Ben!!!